# django 1.4 : I get an error in queryset extra

Tags: python, mysql, django, orm

I have a table `table_object_price`. Fields: `field_sale_currency_value` is the name of the currency, `field_sale_whole_value` is the name of the price.

```
class Object(Node):
   id = models.OneToOneField('Nod', parent_link=True, db_column='id')
   name = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True) 
   field_sale_currency_value = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)  
   field_sale_whole_value = MIntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
```

This SQL code makes sorting:

```
SELECT *,
  CASE field_sale_currency_value
  when 'RUR' then field_sale_whole_value/40
  when 'USD' then field_sale_whole_value
  when 'EUR' then field_sale_whole_value/0.7423
  field_sale_currency_value FROM welhome.welhome_content_type_object ORDER BY cost_usd ;
```

But I need to use django extra because my function gets queryset:

```
def sort_queryset(queryset):
    queryset = queryset.extra(select={'cost_usd':'(case field_sale_currency_value when "RUR" then field_sale_whole_value/40 when "USD" then field_sale_whole_value when "EUR" then field_sale_whole_value/0.7423 end)'}, order_by=["cost_usd"])
return queryset
```

And it does not work.

```
Error Cannot resolve keyword 'cost_usd' into field
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/querysets/#extra):

> If you need to order the resulting queryset using some of the new
>   fields or tables you have included via `extra()` use the order_by
>   parameter to `extra()` and pass in a sequence of strings. These strings
>   should either be model fields (as in the normal `order_by()` method on
>   querysets), of the form `table_name.column_name` or an alias for a
>   column that you specified in the select parameter to `extra()`.

So, you need to do it as:

```
queryset = queryset.extra(select={'cost_usd':'(case field_sale_currency_value when "RUR" then field_sale_whole_value/40 when "USD" then field_sale_whole_value when "EUR" then field_sale_whole_value/0.7423 end)'})
queryset = queryset.extra(order_by = ['cost_usd'])
```

Comment: Thank you but it does not work.  Cannot resolve keyword 'cost_usd' into field

Comment: @voice Make sure you removed the `order_by` call from the first `extra()` call.

Comment: I copied this from pycharm:  queryset = queryset.extra(select={'cost_usd':'(case field_sale_currency_value when "RUR" then field_sale_whole_value/40 when "USD" then field_sale_whole_value when "EUR" then field_sale_whole_value/0.7423 end)'})
            queryset  = queryset.extra(order_by = ['cost_usd'])

Comment: @voice Have you restarted the server after making the changes?

Comment: Yes and I restarted again.

Comment: @voice Then I guess you're facing this bug: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/14930 and they didn't fix it for Django 1.4.

Comment: @voice A quick fix will be to use Python's `sorted()`: `queryset = sorted(queryset, key=lambda x:x.cost_usd)`.

Comment: @voice Or you can make the required changes in your Django files: https://github.com/django/django/commit/2f35c6f10fcbae541691207fb0c0560a13b754fc (better try in a separate virtualenv first).